# iOS - Removing separator between viewForHeaderInSction and first Cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I am using a `UITableView` where i need to remove the 
separator between first cell and `HeaderView` of a `UITableView`. Tried a some solution but nothing worked for me. Any kind of help will be appreciable. attaching screen shot of my current view and expected view 
[image: My current view image] [image: My Expected view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separators are set per tableView, so it's not exactly possible to remove them just per cell.

However, if you set the `tableview.separatorStyle = .none`, and create a fake separator as a view in your cell at the bottom of the cell, you can achieve the look you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

Swift :

```
if indexPath.row == {your row number} {
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
}
```

or :

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
```

for default Margin:

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, tCell.layoutMargins.left, 0, 0)
```

to show separator end-to-end

```
cell.separatorInset = .zero
```

Objective-C:

```
if (indexPath.row == {your row number}) {
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX);
}
```

Comment: Tried that before. It remove the separator line between first and second cell. I need to remove separator between header and first cell

Comment: you can try to hide in your header cell.

Comment: we don't have access to separator view, isn't it?